# folder size wrong

Tags: objective-c, macos, size, osx-lion

This code is correct but the folder size is wrong. If I change the directory the size is always wrong. For example the size of "%@/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Webpage Previews" is 23 MB, but I have 16.5 KB.

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Webpage Previews", [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]];
    NSNumber *fileSize = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:nil] objectForKey:NSFileSize];
    resultsize += [fileSize unsignedLongLongValue];
```

also I used this but the size is always wrong:

```
NSFileManager *fm = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];    
    NSURL *LibraryURL = [[fm URLsForDirectory:NSLibraryDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    NSURL *previewsURL = [LibraryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Caches/com.apple.Safari/Webpage Previews"];

    resultSize += [[[fm attributesOfItemAtPath:[previewsURL path] error:nil] objectForKey:NSFileSize] unsignedIntegerValue];
```

Can you help me?
Thanks.

Comment: I like any post that starts with: this code is correct, but everything else is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get the size of all the files in a folder, you'll need to iterate through the contents of the folder and get the sizes of the actual files:

```
unsigned long long totalSize = 0;
NSFileManager *fm = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSURL *libraryURL = [[fm URLsForDirectory:NSLibraryDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
NSURL *previewsURL = [LibraryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Caches/com.apple.Safari/Webpage Previews"];

NSDirectoryEnumerator *enumerator = [fm enumeratorAtURL:previewsURL includingPropertiesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSURLFileSizeKey] options:0 errorHandler:nil /* or an actual error handler */];

for (NSURL *url in enumerator) {
    NSNumber *sizeNumber;
    if ([url getResourceValue:&sizeNumber forKey:NSURLFileSizeKey error:nil /* or an error */])
        totalSize += [sizeNumber unsignedLongLongValue]; 
}
```

(I haven't tested this.)

Comment: Ok, solved! Thanks! Add  resultSize += [[[fm attributesOfItemAtPath:[previewsURL path] error:nil] objectForKey:NSFileSize] unsignedIntegerValue];

Answer (score -1):

Lion has some kind of Cache for these cumulative sizes. Try on a server volume (Mac OS X Lion Server AFP):

- Open a Folder with lots of Subfolders
- Menu View > as List
- Menu View > Arrange By > Size
- Finder shows all subfolders in the "---" group
- Menu View > Show View Options
- check the box "Calculate all File Sizes"
- now Finders groups the subfolders appropriately
- and even when you close that window, disconnect server and connect again, these sizes are there faster and also when not arranged by size

-> where is this information stored? which API to use?