# How to get total size of contents inside a folder - OS x

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, directory, nsfilemanager

I need to get the total size of contents inside a folder, ie. the same value as displayed in 'GetInfo'. I don't see any direct method to fetch this value.

What I am doing right now is, I am using a recursive method which loops through each contents inside the folder, then get **NSFileSize** attribute of each content, add them up to get the total value. But one issue with this approach is, it's consuming too much of my CPU usage. Is there any alternate method (probably a direct api) which gives me the result?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275627/easy-way-to-get-size-of-folder-objc-cocoa

Comment: refer a Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9064791/folder-size-wrong